# What do jasmine runs and waitsFor actually do?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I use jasmine runs and wait to test asynchronous operations. Everything works fine but I'm not quite sure what goes on behind the scenes.

The jasmine documentation states the following example to which I added three log statement.

```
describe("Asynchronous specs", function() {
  var value, flag;

  it("should support async execution of test preparation and exepectations", function() {

    runs(function() {
      flag = false;
      value = 0;

      setTimeout(function() {
        flag = true;
      }, 500);
    });

    waitsFor(function() {
      value++;
      if(flag) {
          console.log("A");
      }
      return flag;
    }, "The Value should be incremented", 750);

    console.log("B");

    runs(function() {
      console.log("C");
      expect(value).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
  });
});
```

});

The first `runs` and `waitsFor` are perfectly clear to me. `Runs` starts an asynchronous operation and `waitsFor` waits for a condition.

However I do not understand why the second `runs` does not start until the `waitsFor` is finished. The `waitsFor` is not a blocking call.

My guess is that `waitsFor` implicitly blocks any following `runs` call until it is finished. Is this so?

My evidence is that the console.log statements output:

B A C

But if `waitsFor` would really block it should be

A B C

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`waitsFor` does block until the conditions it's waiting for are met or it times out.

From the [jasmine docs](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs#waitsforfunction-optional-message-optional-timeout): "waitsFor() provides a better interface for pausing your spec until some other work has completed. Jasmine will wait until the provided function returns true before continuing with the next block.".

The linked docs also have a slightly clearer example or `waitsFor`.

**EDIT**: Ah I see what you mean now. `waitsFor` won't block JS that isn't wrapped in `runs`, `waitsFor`, ect.

What jasmine is doing is taking the function passed to it via `runs` or `waitsFor` and if jasmine is not currently waiting, it executes the function immediately. If it is waiting, it doesn't call it until it's finished waiting.

That doesn't stop the `console.log` as it's been passed to jasmine so jasmine can't prevent it from being executed straight away.

Comment: I'm quite sure that this is not the case. You put a statement between the `waitsFor` and the second `run` it will be executed before the code in `waitsFor` I will update my question to reflect that.

Comment: But thanks for the link to the documentation, I didn't knew it :)

Comment: And thanks again, the answer is in the docs, but not quite where you pointed :)

Comment: 'waitsFor' not only blocks until the condition is met, but also runs the code inside the function passed to it once every 10ms. Useful to keep this in mind. http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/test-asynchronous-methods-using-the-jasmine-runs-and-waitfor-methods.html#fbid=y73WsLillIO

Answer (score 4):

The solution is in the documentation:

> Multiple runs() blocks in a spec will run serially. ([Jasmine Documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support))

Answer (score 3):

From the site: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/test-asynchronous-methods-using-the-jasmine-runs-and-waitfor-methods.html#fbid=mzNDUVfhFXg

> Jasmine will call the runs() and waitsFor() methods in the order you
>   passed them. As soon as the JS parser gets to a waitsFor() method it
>   will poll it until it returns true and only then will it continue onto
>   the next runs() method.

Essentially, the runs() and waitsFor() functions stuff an array with their provided functions. The array is then processed by jamine wherein the functions are invoked sequentially. Those functions registered by runs() are expected to perform actual work while those registered by waitsFor() are expected to be 'latch' functions and will be polled (invoked) every 10ms until they return true or the optional registered timeout period expires. If the timeout period expires an error is reported using the optional registered error message; otherwise, the process continues with the next function in the array. Presumably, expects within the runs() can also trigger a failure report (and perhaps even in the latch functions themselves).

The documentation is particularly obtuse on these asynchronous features.

Comment: Jasmine 1.3 provides waitsFor-methods (not waitFor) the answer should be corrected.