# Why is using jasmine's runs and waitFor function necessary?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I'm testing an asynchronous piece of code with something that looks like this:

```
randomService.doSomething().then(function() {
    console.log('I completed the operation!');
});
```

Surprisingly (to me) I've found that it only succeeds (ie console.log output is shown) when wrapped inside jasmine's `runs` function, like so:

```
var isDone = false;

runs(function() {
    randomService.doSomething().then(function(data) {
        console.log('I completed the operation!');
        isDone = true;
    });
});

waitsFor(function() {
    return isDone;
}, 'Operation should be completed', 1000);
```

As I understood it, I thought `waitsFor` was only to delay the code, in other words I would use it if I had more code that I had to delay until after the asynchronous call completed - in other words, I would have thought that there'd be no reason for me to use `runs` and `waitsFor` since there's nothing that comes after this bit of code, right? That's the impression I got from reading this question: [What do jasmine runs and waitsFor actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400047/what-do-jasmine-runs-and-waitsfor-actually-do) but obviously I've gotten myself mixed up at some point.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

---

**EDIT:**
Here is a Plunker with far more detail of the problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/3qnuj5N9Thb2UdgoxYaD?p=preview

Note how the first test always passes, and the second test fails as it should. 
Also, I'm sure I should have mentioned this before, but this is using angularJS, and Jasmine 1.3.

Comment: If I may suggest - there is really no good reason to use Jasmine with promises imo now that Mocha has native promises support.

Comment: @Benjamin-Gruenbaum Well I'm definitely open to trying new things, I'd really prefer to stick with Jasmine as the project I'm working on right now is using angularJS, and it seems that Jasmine is the preferred testing method for angular, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: since you're using angular i'd stick with jasmine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the issue. Here's the article: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/webdev/uidevelopment/javascript/testing-asynchronous-javascript-w-jasmine/

Essentially it's necessary because Jasmine doesn't wait for the asynchronous calls to finish before it completes a test. According to the article, if a call takes long enough and there are more tests later, an `expect` statement in an asynchronous callback in a previous test could finally execute in a different test entirely, after the original test completed.

Using `runs` and `waitsFor` solve the problem because they force jasmine to wait for the `waitsFor` to finish before proceeding to the next test; This is a moot point however because evidently Jasmine 2.0 addresses asynchronous testing in a better way than 1.3, obsoleting `runs` and `waitsFor`.

Comment: there you go, that makes sense. glad you were able to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

That's just how Jasmine works. The question you linked has an answer with a decent explanation:

> Essentially, the runs() and waitFor() functions stuff an array with
>   their provided functions. The array is then processed by jamine
>   wherein the functions are invoked sequentially. Those functions
>   registered by runs() are expected to perform actual work while those
>   registered by waitFor() are expected to be 'latch' functions and will
>   be polled (invoked) every 10ms until they return true or the optional
>   registered timeout period expires. If the timeout period expires an
>   error is reported using the optional registered error message;
>   otherwise, the process continues with the next function in the array.

To sum it up, each `waitsFor` call must have a corresponding `runs` call. They work together. Calling `waitsFor` without a `runs` call somewhere before it does not make sense.

---

My revised plunker (see comments on this answer): http://plnkr.co/edit/9eL9d9uERre4Q17lWQmw

As you can see, I added `$rootScope.$apply();` to the the timeout function you were testing with. This makes the `console.log` inside the promise callback run. HOWEVER it only runs if you ignore the other test with an `xit`, AND the `expect` after the `console.log` does not seem to be recognized as a Jasmine test (though it certainly must run, because the `console.log` does).

Very weird - I don't really understand why this is happening, but I think it has something to do with how Jasmine works behind the scenes, how it registers tests and whatnot. My understanding at this point is if you have an `expect` inside an async callback, Jasmine won't "recognize" it as a part of the test suite unless the initial async call was made inside a `runs`.

As for why this is, I don't know. I don't think it's worth trying to understand - I would just use `runs` and `waitsFor` and not worry about it, but that's just me. You can always dig through the source if you're feeling masochistic. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: This part I sort of understand, but what I primarily fail to see is why using `runs` and `waitsFor` is necessary in the first place. I just don't see why that code wouldn't work without them - could you please explain that part to me?

Comment: what happens when you run the code without them? `waitsFor` lets you test for unknown errors and timeouts in a "jasmine" way. typically my `waitsFor` functions do nothing except return a bool. my promises SET the bool depending on if the returned data from the service is correct or not.

Comment: That's the strange part - whatever I have inside the callback function is never executed if I run the jasmine test without using `runs`. If I run the code outside of a testing environment, however, it works perfectly, which is one reason I'm so confused at what Jasmine is doing here.

Comment: oh i see what you mean. the console log doesn't show up? i suspect the code IS being run, but jasmine doesn't see the console log - because you're not using `runs`. not 100% sure *why* this is, but i know that a call to `runs` is an individual test block. i would just use `runs` and smile because jasmine is weird. btw if you're using a headless browser, try chrome and see if the console log appears.

Comment: I guess it's possible that the code is being run, but I don't think so - When I tried putting in a test that's guaranteed to fail (ie `expect(true).toBe(false)` the test still passed, so I think it may not be run at all. I'm definitely using `runs` (I have to for my code to work) but it'd be nice to know _why_ this is the case - I can't stand writing code I don't fully understand...

Comment: i just tried making an async request in a jasmine test without using `runs` - the console log in my `success` function showed up fine. unless there's something wrong with your promise framework, your problem must be somewhere else -- is your code inside an `it` block?

Comment: Yes it is - hold on, I'm going to spin up a JSfiddle to experiment with, the complete example is a little too long to fit in my question description.

Comment: On second thought, I have to go, but as soon as I can I will update the description with a plunker with a few more details. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here is the Plunker with the issue, as promised: http://plnkr.co/edit/3qnuj5N9Thb2UdgoxYaD?p=preview

Comment: weird. check out my revised plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/9eL9d9uERre4Q17lWQmw - i'll update my answer with more.