# Jasmine Async Testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine2.0

I'm attempting to test a value that is set asynchronously using Jasmine 2's new `done()` callback.

I've based my test after the example Jasmine gives in their documentation (http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/upgrading.html#section-Asynchronous_Specs):

```
it('can set a flag after a delay', function(done) {

  var flag = false,
  setFlag = function() {
    //set the flag after a delay
    setTimeout(function() {
        flag = true;
        done();
    }, 100);
  };

  setFlag();
  expect(flag).toBe(true);
});
```

I'm getting the result "Expected false to be true", so I'm guessing that it's not waiting for the done() callback to be invoked before checking the value of the flag.

Does anyone know why this test is failing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're running your assertion as soon as `setTimeout` has been call, thus you're not giving it enough time to invoke the callback that sets flag to true. The below code will work (run the below code at [TryJasmine](http://tryjasmine.com/) to see how it behaves):

```
describe('flag delays', function () {
  it('can set a flag after a delay', function(done) {
    var flag = false,
    setFlag = function() {
      //set the flag after a delay
      setTimeout(function() {
          flag = true;
          expect(flag).toBe(true);
          done();
      }, 100);
    };

    setFlag();
  });
});
```

Going forward, Jasmine has a [`waitsFor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400047/what-do-jasmine-runs-and-waitsfor-actually-do) method to facilitate testing timers. Even better, [Sinon.JS](http://sinonjs.org/docs/) provides functionality for [faking times](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock), which enables to skip `setTimeout` invocations and verify any behaviour without creating duration-based dependencies in your tests. Additionally, you'll be able to write assertions at the end of your tests as your did in your question, which will massively improve readability.

Comment: Ah I see. I was hoping that Jasmine 2 gave expect() some extra powers to see if it should wait for a done() callback. It looks like adding done as a parameter to it() just tells it to wait until done() has been called before moving on to the next test. right?

Comment: Sinon.js looks very cool. I came across Jasmine.tick as well, which looks like it can mock setTimeouts as well: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Mocking_the_JavaScript_Timeout_Functions

Comment: @corbin That's right. I've used it in my Mocha tests, as that framework supports the same approach. For my async stuff, I use the fake timers (which admittedly I only encountered a few days ago!) and `Promise`s, which can be returned directly to the Mocha test runner; that means you don't even need to invoke `done`! I'm not sure if Karma behaves in the same way though.