# With Jasmine, how do I test an async call using callFake() and done()?

Tags: javascript, testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I am using jasmine's [new syntax (so no `waits`, or `runs`)](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) for testing asynchronous operations, and am having trouble.

What I am trying to do is ensure that the render function is called when the model triggers a `sync` event. This example is trivial, but demonstrates the core problem I have. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828108/jasmine-async-testing) comes close to my use case, but is ultimately different due to the setTimeout, which I do not have.

What I've tried is:

### my function

```
postLoad : function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
},
```

### my test

```
describe('postLoad', function () {

    it('listens to model sync and calls render', function (done) {
        //arrange
        view = new App.View({ model: model });
        view.initialize();
        view.postLoad();

        spyOn(view, 'render').and.callFake(function () {
            done();
        });

        //act
        view.model.trigger('sync');

        //assert
        expect(view.render.calls.count()).toBe(1);

    });
});
```

The above seems reasonable sense `render` may take a while, but from what I understand currently with `done`, the spec will not evaluate until it's called. I am hoping someone can come to the rescue!  Since we are faking render does it not get counted in the spy?

Comment: Does your test timeout or does it throw an error ?

Comment: It times out: `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as `this.view.model.trigger('sync');` triggers a call to `view.render` as it seems to, this *should* work I think.

```
describe('postLoad', function() {
    beforeEach(function(done) {
        this.view = new App.View({ model: model });
        spyOn(this.view, 'render').and.callFake(done);
        this.view.initialize();
        this.view.postLoad();
        this.view.model.trigger('sync');
    });
    it('listens to model sync and calls render', function() {
        expect(this.view.render.calls.count()).toBe(1);
    });
});
```