# Promise .then not triggering when using Karma + Jasmine + PhantomJs?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, es6-promise

My unit test is not working hitting the `then` function for some reason. Here is the test code.

```
describe("Basic promise test", () => {
    it("should trigger .then function", () => {
        var mock = jasmine.createSpy('some method');
        var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
            console.log("inside Promise");
            resolve('something');
            console.log("done!");
        });
        promise.then(mock);         
        promise.then(function () {   //neither works!
            mock();
            console.log("resolved"); //code does reach here but only after test fails
        });

        expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

I've tried using 'babel-polyfill', 'es6-promise' and 'promise-polyfill' to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Jsfiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/L53zxe39/

Comment: The promise resolves *asynchronously*, so you need to use jasmine's async testing features. According to [this article](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/test-asynchronous-methods-using-the-jasmine-runs-and-waitfor-methods.html#fbid=Pr4UoAyeYCM) and [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16401978/157247), that involves using `runs` and `waitsFor`. I'd post it as an answer, but I know nothing about jasmine, maybe there's something more specific for promise testing than `runs` and `waitsFor`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder please see the jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/L53zxe39/. I've already tried using `waitsFor` but it throws an error because I'm using Jasmine 2.0 (i think they've removed it)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I didn't post an answer, I just don't know jasmine, couldn't tell the age of the article, and the answer I found was from 2013 before promises were really big. But fundamentally, the issue is that the resolution is async, so jasmine needs to know that. So look at the jasmine docs for the current way to test promise-based APIs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The promise is resolved, but the `then` callback is only called in the next microtask, **after** the check `expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();` has been made.

It is intended behaviour and designed to prevent ambiguity around promises. A `.then` callback is guaranteed to be called later, even if the promise is already resolved.

Asynchronous jasmine tests work in the following way:

```
describe("Basic promise test", () => {
    it("should trigger .then function", (done) => {
        var mock = jasmine.createSpy('some method');
        var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
            console.log("inside Promise");
            resolve('something');
            console.log("done!");
        });
        promise.then(mock).then(() => {
          expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
          done();
        }).catch(e => {
          done.fail(e);
        });
    });
});
```

You can use `done.fail` to explicitly fail the spec. This is needed to catch and notify jasmine about uncaught exceptions during tests.